# Why is $W^{1,p}(\Omega;S)$ weakly closed in $W^{1,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)$ for a compact set $S$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Recall the definition of the vector valued Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is either $\mathbb R^n$ or a $C^1$ bounded domain, and $1<p<\infty$ — we say $u\in L^p(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)$ is in $W^{1,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)$ if $\mathrm Du \in L^p(\Omega;\mathbb R^{nN})$, with the usual norm. For any compact set $S\subset\mathbb R^N$, we can also define $$W^{1,p}(\Omega;S):=\{u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)\ :\ u(\cdot)\subset S\hbox{ a.e.}\}$$ which can be sen to be strongly closed.

However, without any convexity assumption on $S$, why is it the case that $W^{1,p}(\Omega;S)$ is weakly closed? Recall that $W^{1,p}(\Omega;\mathbb R^N)$ is reflexive.

Comment: Just a notation remark: the condition "$u(\Omega) \subset S$ up to a set of measure zero" makes sense if you're referring to the _essential image_ of $u$. It seems safer though to write "$u(x) \in S$ a.e.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rellich-Kondrachov theorem (applied to $B_r (x) \subset\subset \Omega$ for $x\in\Omega$ arbitrary and $r>0$ sufficiently small) implies $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^p_{loc}(\Omega)$, where the embedding is **compact**.

Hence, if $f_n \to f$ weakly in your vector valued Sobolev space and with $f_n$ taking values in $S$ almost everywhere, then there is a subsequence with $f_n \to f$ almost surely. Since $S$ is closed (we do not need compactness actually), this implies that $f$ also takes values in $S$ almost surely.

Comment: I’m probably just forgetting a very basic fact in functional analysis, but why is it the case that a compact map is cont. w.r.t. the weak topology on the source Banach space?

Comment: @Monstrous: Assume $T$ is compact and $f_n \to f$ weakly. Then $T f_n \to T f$ weakly. Furthermore, $(f_n)_n$ is bounded, so that $T f_{n_k}\to g$ strongly for some subsequence by compactness. This entails $g = T f$, i.e. $T f_{n_k} \to Tf$ strongly. Finally, if it was not true that $T f_n \to Tf$ strongly, there would be a subsequence $(f_{n_\ell})$ with $\|Tf_{n_\ell} -Tf\|>\epsilon$ for all $\ell$. If you now do the argument from the beginning of the proof for this subsequence, you get a contradiction.

Comment: @Monstrous: I just noted a slight problem: My argument only proves weak **sequential** continuity. My answer also only proves that your set is weakly **sequentially** closed. That probably suffices for the application that you have in mind (does it?), but it would still be interesting to know whether your set is actually weakly closed. I will think about it.

Comment: It seems that your argument above works for nets (generalized sequences) just as well, so it proves standard continuity.

Comment: @Micha: Yes, I guess this part will work :) But in the actual answer I also use that a strongly $L^p$ convergent sequence has an a.e. convergent subsequence. I guess this will fail for nets.